# Issue running page inside Facebook Tab, only IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have an ecommerce page that I am trying to run inside a facebook tab. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but with Internet Explorer, a couple of functions aren't working and not sure why.

Here is the [FB tab page](https://www.facebook.com/ExtremeLedLightBars/app_162396490606786). If you click on a product and then click either the Add to Cart or Add to Wishlist buttons, the page just refreshes, but the Wishlist or Cart do not increment.

If I run the IE Script debugger, and have it break on All Exceptions, I see several, but not sure exactly what they mean.

When the page loads, here is the first exception:

```
SCRIPT5022: Caught exception occurred : SyntaxError 
jquery.min.js, line 3 character 22902
```

Looking at the source code for this error:

```
b.call(c.documentElement,"[test!='']:sizzle")
```

Note this site is using jquery 1.6.

If you run [the page](http://secure5.realssl.com/ssl/fbstore/tabid/549/ProdID/3/Extreme6inch2880LumenLEDlightbar.aspx) in IE directly, there are no issues.

Comment: Well post the exceptions

Comment: Sorry, added the first error.